# Can sequelize.transaction() take async function as callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sequelize.js

So reading through the Sequelize documentation on [Instance](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-transaction) and also docs about [transactions](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/transactions.html), the `sequelize.transaction()` takes `autoCallback` function as parameter. The docs say:

> The callback is called with the transaction object, and should return
>   a promise. If the promise is resolved, the transaction commits; if the
>   promise rejects, the transaction rolls back

However I plan to do a lot of things inside on transaction and I want to avoid the callback hell. So I tried to make

```
try {
    let result = sequelize.transaction({
            isolationLevel: 'SERIALIZABLE'
        }, async t => {
            // code to run here with await
            let var1 = await Model.find({ transaction: t });
            let var2 = await Model.find({ transaction: t });

            if (var1.id === 1)
                return "Whatever result";
            else
                throw new Error("Something wicked");
        }
    )});

    // Whatever result
    console.log(result);
}catch(e){
    // Something wicked
}
```

This seems to be working perfectly fine. But it is totally undocumented and I havent seen anybody use this. Is it ok, or will I face random issues?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "totally undocumented". The docs say "*should return a promise*", and you are using an `async function`, so everything is fine?

Comment: @Bergi yes, I hope everything is fine. I am just asking for a confirmation. If I understand correctly, I must not return a promise from async callback function (like return Model.find()) but I must always return a value itself (like return await Model.find()), correct?

Comment: @michnovka every async function returns a promise. If Model.find returns a promise, then there is no significant difference between `return Model.find()` and `return await Model.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) and [@Nicholas Tower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3794812/nicholas-tower) pointed out in comments:

Since async function ALWAYS returns promise and the callback function should return a promise, this is rather straight-forward answer.

Yes, it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing styles, if you want to use straight async/await see below. You are also not passing the transaction (`t` in your code) to the query, so they won't use it - you have to pass it explicitly in the `transaction` option. If you make any changes after you should commit the transaction, and subsequently roll it back if there are any errors. You can also improve your code by running the queries concurrently with `Promise.all()`.

```
// define outside the try/catch so you can rollback if needed
let transaction;
let result;
try {
    transaction = await sequelize.transaction({ isolationLevel: 'SERIALIZABLE' });

    // run concurrently with Promise.all()
    const [ var1, var2 ] = await Promise.all([
       // don't await here, but you have to pass the transaction
       Model.findByPk({ transaction }),
       Model.findOne({ transaction }), // ditto
    ]);

    if (var1.id === 1) {
       result = "Whatever result";
    } else {
       throw new Error("Something wicked");
    }
    // if you need to commit anything...
    // await transaction.commit();
} catch(err) {
    /* if you need to roll back anything...
    if (transaction) {
       await transaction.rollback();
    }
    */
    console.log(err);
}
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but even tho your solution does work, so does mine. But by not providing callback to the transaction function, you need to manually call commit() and rollback(). This is taken care of automatically by sequelize in case of supplying callback to the function. Thanks anyways

Comment: @michnovka the transaction is not being passed to the queries so it is not being used. Your answer was on the right track though.

Comment: @michnovka the commit and rollback will happen automatically but I find that's not the best practice for production apps as it's best to control the point that the rollback happens in case you need to do anything after, but that's not true for all use cases hence it's commented out in the example.